# Installing DIMM modules in HP ProLiant DL180G6 not in recommended order

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

I have two DL180G6 servers, I used them with 2x2 GB RAM modules, now I'd like to upgrade the memory to 16 GB for each. I have spare 6x2 GB RAM modules per machine (parameters match for the existing ones), but when I populate the remaining slots (these slots were empty from the beginning), one of the RAMs seems to be missing - 2 GB is missing in total memory.

I have made some trial-and-error checking on the slots, it seems both machines have one slot where the memory could not be identified, the memory modules are working fine.

The warranties have just expired on both machines.

I've been following the recommended population order for the memories.

My question is: what happens if I don't follow the population order, will be the machine and memories still be usable or will it damage the RAM/CPU/MB?

Also, I've seen in the specs that it is not required to have both RAM blocks filled with same amount of DIMM module. Would it be feasible to fill one bank with only one module (the second one is the faulty(?)) and fill the rest of the memory in the other?

Thanks for the answers in advance!

**Edit #1**

I have two CPUs installed in both servers (P/N: *482601-002*, *586641-001*), also the P/N for the RAMs are all *500202-061*.

**Edit #2**

On one machine the first slot on the second channel for the second CPU (the one farther from the front panel) seems to be faulty while on the other machine the first slot on the third channel for the second CPU.

That is in the first case:

`(ch3/2 none) (ch3/1 none) (ch2/2 none) (ch2/1 FAIL) (ch1/2 none) (ch1/1 OK) [CPU]`

`[CPU] (ch1/1 OK) (ch1/2 none) (ch2/1 OK) (ch2/2 none) (ch3/1 none) (ch3/2 none)`

That is in the second case:

`(ch3/2 none) (ch3/1 FAIL) (ch2/2 none) (ch2/1 OK) (ch1/2 none) (ch1/1 OK) [CPU]`

`[CPU] (ch1/1 OK) (ch1/2 none) (ch2/1 OK) (ch2/2 none) (ch3/1 OK) (ch3/2 none)`

`OK` means RAM is working perfectly, `FAIL` means no RAM in any combinations are detected in that slot. `none` is an empty slot (as it should be according to the population recommendation).

Comment: What is the part number of the RAM in your machines?

Comment: how many processors are installed on these machines as well...

Comment: I have 2 processors installed (P/N: 482601-002, 586641-001), and RAM P/N is 500202-061 for all of them.

Answer (score 5):

Servers on this platform have specific DIMM population guidelines. But most of those won't matter except that you're probably using 2GB UDIMMs and that you may only have one processor installed.

If these are UDIMMs, you are allowed to fill two slots per DIMM channel. You mentioned that half of the DIMM slots were initially empty. If you only have one CPU, you can't use half of the slots on the system.

Populate the white slots first, then fill in each channel with the second DIMM.

[image]

Comment: I am using 2 GB DIMM modules indeed and have two CPUs. (Added their exact part numbers in the question.)

Comment: Some clarification: I had 2 of 2 GB modules initially. When I try to place more modules the problem happens that I described above (added a description of the exact slots and modules). I would like to fill the RAMs evenly if possible, but I just can't place the second module (the third for the other server) for CPU2.